# django admin page will not post when updating user pages in admin console

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to deploy a django site.  It appears to work correctly, however in the admin site, it appears that POST is not working for updating user accounts.

the error response is located here: http://dpaste.com/0CKD2CS

My question here, is if django-admin is running normally, why would a website not find the page in a POST setting?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The `FileNotFoundError` in this case actually originates with an attempt to read a "format file", which is used by Django for determining locale-specific formats for things like dates, times, and currency display. In this case it's on the `DATE_INPUT_FORMATS` for the `DateField`.

Django allows the path for formats to be specified in settings:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#format-module-path

Otherwise there are a number of these configured in a locale directory in the Django distribution - `.../lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/locale`. For example:

```
../lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/locale/en_AU/formats.py
19:DATE_INPUT_FORMATS = (
20-    '%d/%m/%Y', '%d/%m/%y',             # '25/10/2006', '25/10/06'
21-    # '%b %d %Y', '%b %d, %Y',          # 'Oct 25 2006', 'Oct 25, 2006'
22-    # '%d %b %Y', '%d %b, %Y',          # '25 Oct 2006', '25 Oct, 2006'
23-    # '%B %d %Y', '%B %d, %Y',          # 'October 25 2006', 'October 25, 2006'
24-    # '%d %B %Y', '%d %B, %Y',          # '25 October 2006', '25 October, 2006'
25-)
```

Worth examining the effective locale and associated files. If you can live with disabling the translation machinery, or perhaps at least while troubleshooting, you can set `USE_I18N=False` in `settings`.

Possibly worth perusing the Django [Internationalization and Localization](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/i18n/) docs.

Django will use `en` if there isn't a country-specific format module, so that will be fine. You can try using a Django shell in the project to attempt the equivalent call:

```
$ ./manage.py shell
>>> import datetime
>>> datetime.datetime.strptime('2015-10-19', '%Y-%m-%d').date()
datetime.date(2015, 10, 19)
```

The only place there is Django-related file I/O is in the loading of the format module so as long as `django/conf/locale/en/formats.py` is available then the possibilities for such failure are limited, failing something strange happening with `datetime`, which seems improbable. There is a fallback for the formats in that Django will retrieve from `settings`, so you could add this line to your `settings`:

```
DATE_INPUT_FORMATS = ( '%Y-%m-%d', '%m/%d/%Y', '%m/%d/%y')
```

Comment: This is an interesting part of the django featureset that I have not examined before.  To start, I attempted to update settings.py with USE_I18N=False as recommended, however, I am still seeing the error.  Where else can I go look?

Comment: That's unfortunate. What's the current locale? Perhaps you can check in `/root/.virtualenvs/ifthq/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/conf/locale` subdirectories for the matching module file and see how the formats are (or are not) defined.

Comment: Also, thinking about this, the `USE_L10N` setting is likely more relevant in this case, as it did boil down to date formats - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#std:setting-USE_L10N

Comment: I did change USE_L10N to FALSE as well, and still receive the error.  Within the locale folder, there is 20 folders, to include en and some alternate en folders (ie. en-gb, en-au, etc.)  Unfortunately, I still have the error.

Comment: What are the current locale and language settings?

Comment: Another thing you could do is get the PID of the running process and then `strace` it to check for the file access. This would be something like `strace -p 6416 > strace.log 2>&1` (assuming Linux), you could then check strace.log for `ENOENT` to determine the file it's attempted to open but failed on. *** This will produce a lot of output *** so you'd probably just want to run the strace for as short a period as possible.

Comment: ok.  I looked at settings.py.  The current locale was "EN_us".  Noticing there was no EN_us in the folder.  there was, however, a "en" in the folder, but that didn't work either.